# How does one pay for the Transcaribe bus in Cartagena?

Tags: public-transport, payment-cards, colombia, cartagena

I'm in Cartagena, Colombia, and want to ride the [Transcaribe bus network](https://transcaribe.gov.co/) to get around town. However, I can not figure out how to pay for a ride!

Internet research suggests that one should buy a payment card at a BRT station. I walked to such a station—one of the main stations in the historic center of the city—stood in line at the *taquilla* (ticket counter) and asked for *una tarjeta con crédito de 20.000 pesos* and was told that they do not sell cards at that station! I then tried a tactic that works in many cities around the world and walked into a minimarket, and was told that bus cards are not available there either.

What is the solution here? I see the buses going by, often quite full, so clearly there is some means to get on them. Is *una tarjeta* the wrong thing to ask for? Is there some secret place to go to get cards instead? None of the places on the [red de recarga externa](https://transcaribe.gov.co/index.php/red_de_recarga/) are particularly close to me, but I could get to one if I were sure they sold new cards and not just *recargas*.

I've ridden public transit in all kinds of cities all around the world, and never been so puzzled. My Spanish is limited but, in my experience, usually more than good enough for simple transactions like this. What am I doing wrong?